# Join dataframes by a column of ids, updating and adding missing data

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to join two dataframes in pandas based on a column with 'ids' in order to fill the missing data and update the existing ones that are not empty, as well add new ids records, as in the fictitious example:

```
df1 = {
"animal_id": ["a12", "a17", "a45"],
"name": ["Lucy", "Lola", "Duke"],
"race": ["Akita", "Beagle", "Boxer"],
"weight": ["", "13", "23"],
"date": ["2020-12-01", "2019-03-08", "2017-10-21"]
}

df2 =
{
"animal_id": ["a12", "a20", "a45", "a71"],
"race": ["Akita", "Pug", "Boxer", "Poodle"],
"weight": ["23", "19", "25", "10.4"],
"pedigree": ["1","1","1","0"]
}

Desired result:

df = {
"animal_id": ["a12", "a17", "a20", "a45", "a71"],
"name": ["Lucy", "Lola", "", "Duke", ""],
"race": ["Akita", "Beagle", "Pug", "Boxer", "Poodle"],
"weight": ["23", "13", "19", "25", "10.4"],
"pedigree": ["1", "", "1", "1", "0"],
"date": ["2020-12-01", "2019-03-08", "", "2017-10-21", ""]
}
```

I tried using `pd.merge` with `how='outer'` but got rows with duplicate id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concat your dataframes then keep the last valid value:

```
out = (pd.concat([df1.replace('', None), df2])
         .groupby('animal_id', as_index=False)
         .last().fillna(''))
print(out)

# Output
  animal_id  name    race weight pedigree        date
0       a12  Lucy   Akita     23        1  2020-12-01
1       a17  Lola  Beagle     13           2019-03-08
2       a20           Pug     19        1            
3       a45  Duke   Boxer     25        1  2017-10-21
4       a71        Poodle   10.4        0
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly. It joined as I wanted over 2200 records.